# Testing `avoidpartialspends` option in Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, coin-selection

I have lot of UTXOs in a test wallet (Bitcoin Core v0.21.1). Sent random amounts to same address in 9 transactions. So `tb1qyqd9p9d2rc5a9v6cphucn999ljfcvdhymthypy` has 9 UTXOs:

[image: inputs]

Saved `avoidpartialspends=1` in `bitcoin.conf`

Tried sending 0.051 BTC to `tb1q57fjyqp3qu9s83eyu4qvy7hzuncg4t0c58t8cm`

Why does coin selection algorithm select 63 other inputs from wallet instead of using 9 from `tb1qyqd9p9d2rc5a9v6cphucn999ljfcvdhymthypy` in [`13eda62acf58fdcb5a34565f993d7af856b54f69c9c73c83db97bf8111c46148`](https://tbtc.bitaps.com/13eda62acf58fdcb5a34565f993d7af856b54f69c9c73c83db97bf8111c46148)? This selection was neither based on privacy nor fees. Using 9 inputs could have saved fees, join several outputs from the reused address and send change amount to a new address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, it is because Bitcoin Core prefers to make transactions which do not create change over anything else. Notice how this transaction does not have any change. If the Branch and Bound exact matching algorithm finds a solution, it is always used, regardless of other "optimality" as it considers "no change" to be an optimal solution.

Obviously this may not be actually be optimal, but there are planned changes to the way coin selection works to have different metrics for "optimal".